# Creating multiple plots on one figure with a for loop using unique in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Using a for loop I need to make three separate plots with regression lines on the same figure, using a unique value that is found in one the group column. (3 plots with different data and regression lines).

```
Group  Height  Weight
A       5.6     59.5
A       5.9     68.7
B       4.8     57.1
B       5.0     42.9
C       7.3     43.3
C       7.1     39.7
```

I tried this code which only gives me the points for group C for some reason? I don't think this is what I really want though, as I need the points with a regression line.

```
for(i in unique(df$Group)){
example<-subset(df,df$Group==i)
plot(example$Height,example$Weight)
}
```

I need one set of data points for each Group A, B, and C on one figure with a regression line for each, using a for loop.

Comment: it sounds like you want facets from `ggplot` http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html

Comment: You are generating three plots - `plot` just rewrites over the top each time, which means you only get the last plot, for `C` being visible.

Comment: Also relevant if going to ggplot land - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727433/how-can-i-add-regression-lines-to-a-plot-that-has-multiple-data-series-that-are

Comment: what should I use instead of plot inside the for loop? without using ggplot